LlamaIndex import error: Plain typing.TypeAlias is not valid as type argument
I am working on a RAG LLM app using LlamaIndex and OpenAI, where I will index and query multiple PDFs.
I have installed llama_index correctly in my environment. However, every time I import SimpleDirectoryReader or VectorStoreIndex from llama_index.core, I get the error
"TypeError: Plain typing.TypeAlias is not valid as type argument."


Change your import to the following:
from llama_index.legacy import VectorStoreIndex


don't use llama_index.legacy, please use the lastest docs and imports
I don't know the source of this specific error (I couldn't reproduce), but fixing it once and for all here
https://github.com/run-llama/llama_index/pull/17394

Hi @Ayush Garg If you use python 3.10 and llamaindex version >= 0.10.37, it raises this bug. This is because the dataclass thinks the TypeAlias is a field (because it has a type annotation that is not ClassVar). You can see it in import of Document. To fix it, you should downgrade python version < 3.10 (the best option is 3.9); in this while, the TypeAlias will be Any.
